# How to disable security on wcf service?

Tags: c#, wcf, net.tcp

I've written a WCF App with the following config in the the app.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="ProxyService">
            <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/ProxyService" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="ServiceProxy" contract="IProxyService"/>
        </service>
      <service name="PublishSubscribeService">
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/PublishSubscribeService" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="PublishSubscribeServer" contract="IPublishSubscribeService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And I'm having an issue with the netTcp Binding rejecting request (I've included the other service just in case it might have an effect but I don't think it does). I'm instantiating it using the following code:

```
private ServiceHost incomingPipeHost;
private ServiceHost incomingSubscribeHost;

incomingPipeHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ProxyService));
incomingPipeHost.Open();

incomingSubscribeHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(PublishSubscribeService));
incomingSubscribeHost.Open();
```

This all works fine when I try to connect to the net.tcp service from a client running locally, and I have had this running fine on a customer site for well over a year. However, I'm now at a different customer site and when I try to connect from a remote machine I get the following exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: The server has rejected the client credentials. ---> System.Security.Authentication.InvalidCredentialException: The server has rejected the client credentials. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The logon attempt failed
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartReceiveBlob(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextSend(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartReceiveBlob(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.AuthenticateAsClient(NetworkCredential credential, ChannelBinding binding, String targetName, ProtectionLevel requiredProtectionLevel, TokenImpersonationLevel allowedImpersonationLevel)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.AuthenticateAsClient(NetworkCredential credential, String targetName, ProtectionLevel requiredProtectionLevel, TokenImpersonationLevel allowedImpersonationLevel)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeProvider.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeInitiator.OnInitiateUpgrade(Stream stream, SecurityMessageProperty& remoteSecurity)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeProvider.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeInitiator.OnInitiateUpgrade(Stream stream, SecurityMessageProperty& remoteSecurity)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamSecurityUpgradeInitiatorBase.InitiateUpgrade(Stream stream)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionUpgradeHelper.InitiateUpgrade(StreamUpgradeInitiator upgradeInitiator, IConnection& connection, ClientFramingDecoder decoder, IDefaultCommunicationTimeouts defaultTimeouts, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.SendPreamble(IConnection connection, ArraySegment`1 preamble, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.DuplexConnectionPoolHelper.AcceptPooledConnection(IConnection connection, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at ....PublishSubscribeServiceLibrary.IPublishSubscribeService.Subscribe(UserData userData)
   at ....PublishSubscribeServiceLibrary.PublishSubscribeClient.Subscribe(UserData userData)
   at ....OnConnected()
```

I've tried adding the following snippet to the system.ServiceModel to disable authentication and I still get the same error:

```
<bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="netTcpBindingConfig" transferMode="Buffered" maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880">
            <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="5242880" />
            <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

What am I doing wrong? and what can I do to try and either disable authentication (which is not a requirement) or get authentication working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the EndPoint with the `netTcpBinding` to use the correct configuration (`netTcpBindingConfig`):

```
<service name="PublishSubscribeService">
  <endpoint ... bindingConfiguration="netTcpBindingConfig" ... />
</service>
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to have turned off the security on the server side but it looks like the client was accessing the service from a different domain which was causing the authentication issue. I'm going to resolve that issue rather than remove security.